# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in SetApartmentState

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception, apartment-state

I have such piece of code:

```
var t = new Thread(ShowStatus);
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

And once I've got exception `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on second line. How is it possible? And what can I do to prevent it from happenning again later?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you debugging your own project output? Or debugging some exe built on some other machine (your build server)? If your symbols are incorrect it can show you wrong line of source code where the exception occurs in debugger.

Comment: I'm using .exe built on build server. So in my case, it can be that problem is in some other line of code?

Comment: Ask your build team whether they store symbols for each build. Get those symbols, it'll show you correct line of code. But anyway, when you get the exception, see the Stack Trace inside exception, it may give you some more clue.

Comment: Thanks, for the help, you can post your explanation and advices as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugger can show you wrong line of source code if symbols are incorrect. Verify your exception source from stack trace in the exception.